# Angular UI Select : Error while using filter inside object properties. Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-select

**Plunkr** : http://plnkr.co/edit/VR4p6n8rbrGZZOCcCrIa?p=preview

I am using angular-ui-select plugin.

I am trying to filter the items based on city, state as well as country.

My data for binding the dropdown has the following structure :

```
  vm.people = [
{ name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 12, 
   state: {state:"NY", country:{country:"US"}
  }

},
{ name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12 
  , state: {state:"ca", country:{country:"US"}
  }

},
{ name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefania@email.com', age: 21 
  , state: {state:"al", country:{country:"US"}
  }

},
{ name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21
  , state: {state:"po", country:{country:"US"}
  }

},
{ name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30
  , state: {state:"mn", country:{country:"US"}
  }

},
{ name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 30
  , state: {state:"na", country:{country:"US"}
  }

},
{ name: 'Nicole',    email: 'nicole@email.com',    age: 43

  , state: {state:"NX", country:{country:"US"}
  }
},
{ name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54
  , state: {state:"NY", country:{country:"US"}
  }

},
{ name: 'Michael',   email: 'michael@email.com',   age: 15
  , state: {state:"NY", country:{country:"US"}
  }

},
{ name: 'Nicolás',   email: 'nicolas@email.com',    age: 43
, state: {state:"NY", country:{country:"US"}
  } 

}
```

];

I am binding it as follows :

```
<ui-select ng-model="ctrl.person.selected" theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a person in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="item in ctrl.people |  propsFilter: {name: $select.search, state.state: $select.search,state.country.country: $select.search} ">
              <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
              <small ng-bind-html="item.email | highlight: $select.search"></small>
            </ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>
```

I am getting this error :

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected,
>   expecting [:] at column 57 of the expression [ctrl.people | 
>   propsFilter: {name: $select.search, state.state:
>   $select.search,state.country.country: $select.search}] starting at
>   [.state: $select.search,state.country.country: $select.search}].

**Edit:** 
I could solve this error by using **filter** instead of **propsfilter** & search in whole json. but i dont want to do that as there are many columns in json which I don't even show to the user..

Answer (score 0):

You can have dynamic object names on the left hand side of the object

Change

```
   <ui-select-choices repeat="item in ctrl.people |  propsFilter: {name: $select.search, state.state: $select.search,state.country.country: $select.search} ">
```

to

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="item in ctrl.people |  propsFilter: {name: $select.search, state: $select.search,country: $select.search}
```

Comment: it still gives error. Error: item[prop] is undefined

Comment: add if ( item[prop] && item[prop])
also u might need to change your item processing , now it gets the objct 
{name: 'a',
country; 'a',
state: 'a'}

Comment: can u plz change the plunkr to reflect it. I am still facing the error

Comment: If you type NY , then u can see that it is not searching for michael & nicholas

Comment: the problem is searching inside the object's properties which are objects..